# SSL error for subdomains with cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I've tried to enable SSL on my Cloudflare account for my asset subdomains, but I see the following error in Chrome:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> a1.staging.domain.com sent an invalid response.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

And this in Firefox:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to a1.staging.domain.com. Peer reports it experienced an internal error. Error code:
>
> SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed this up with Cloudflare support. Turns out that this is due to the limitation that the Cloudflare issued SSL cert is only valid for a single subdomain. So *.domain.com will work, but *.staging.domain.com won't.

More info here:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170566-Why-isn-t-SSL-working-for-my-site-